# Ubuntu 22.04.01: freeze-ups on refreshing from locked screen

Tags: 22.04, freeze, lock-screen

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.01 last week, I have occasional freeze-ups on refreshing from a locked screen.  My lock-screen requires my password to complete the re-opening.  The freeze-ups occur about every fourth time.  To recover, I have to power the desktop off and then restart.  Obviously, an annoyance that I never had in 20.04.  Any suggestions?

---

Now, about a month later, with a belated thank-you to Mossroy for his workaround. However, something seems to have been fixed in the underlying software.  I have **not** had **any** of the above-mentioned freeze-ups since October 6, with about a fifty flawless wake-ups after that.  Someone among the Ubuntu update maintainers must have learned about the problem -- perhaps even from here -- and fixed it.  There has been at least one, maybe several, system updates since that last freeze-up.

---

My first answer is not entirely correct, and it may have been unfair for me to put the blame on the Super-L keystroke.  Letting the screen lock happen with the automatic delay, I find, *now also leads to occasional freeze-ups*.  However, I have now discovered that I do *not* have to power-down-and-up to restart.  If I have typed my log-in password completely, despite the frozen password-entry box, if I  wait about 40 seconds, the screen goes black.  After another lengthy wait, also probably less than a minute, the machine wakes up and displays my desktop!  And nothing seems to have been lost in the process.

---

I am now pretty sure where the trouble was.  I was in the habit of locking the screen with the Super-L keystroke, and that may where the freeze-ups  come from.  When I (finally!) opened up the Ubuntu Settings, I discovered (under Privacy > Screen) that the Automatic Screen Lock **was not on.**  Turning it on and adjusting the delay time to 3 minutes, I was able to check, now about four or five times, that entering my password re-opened the desktop to where I was, with no freeze-up problem.

As a bonus for doing the screen lock automatically, I find that the screen immediately goes black.  With the Super-L key it usually (but not always) displays a bright screen with the password-entry-box and the time. And sometimes it stays that way all night.

Comment: did you check journalctl for logs for when the laptop locked and froze up? compare to when it unlocks properly

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It is a very serious problem in my opinion that Canonical must address now. In my case I have to restart the computer randomly because it freezes after some automatic screen locks, it doesn't happen every day but it does happen some days. In my opinion it happens more when I have a Snap application like Firefox open, so it is probably a problem with Snap and one of its applications. I have read in some forum that a user solved the problem by installing Firefox from deb packages after Snap. I am going to watch and monitor some of the snap processes. Other users relate it to AMD GPU drivers. I'm still paying attention to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem - my lock screen would turn black after I pressed a button or moved the mouse to show the password field, and would remain black until I pressed a key or moved the mouse again. Firefox snap wasn't running, but was installed, so I removed it and the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, on 3 different computers (all upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04).

I found at least a workaround: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. It should bring you again on the login screen. You type the password again, and you're back in your session.

However, it's only a workaround.

I've found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1975884 that describes the same symptoms, but I do not always have his error message in my /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 0):

I locked my desktop via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Nothing in the above advice was helpful. All that blind-typing my password achieved was to bring up a blank desktop with no app icons or status bar, and nothing to do except reboot. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> didn't seem to do anything useful. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> has on occasion brought up a bare command prompt login that I do not have the expertise to do anything useful with.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1259759)