# Ubuntu 22.04.1 - screen freeze when resuming from locked screen

Tags: 22.04, freeze, lock-screen

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 few weeks ago. I sometime experience the following problem:

When I try resume session from auto-locked screen sometimes the screen freeze and I am not able to enter the password. The login screen is correctly shown but it is not possible to input the password (actually sometimes freeze happens after the first characters of the password have been entered with dots shown on screen). This seem to happen randomly every 4-5 times. Only way to resume seems to be by closing the lid of the laptop (suspend) and opening again. I'd like to solve this or file a bug. Can anyone help or have a clue?

Comment: The issue appear to be somehow similar to the one reported here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426815/ubuntu-22-04-01-freeze-ups-on-refreshing-from-locked-screen but I actually have auto-lock already enabled...

Comment: Same for me, but see my postings of today and September 1 about this problem.  Finish typing in your password, wait until the screen goes black, and then wait until your desktop reappears.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I read your last post just now. I also verified that after entering the password and a long wait with frozen screen the desktop reappears with successful login. I checked journalctl and the problem do not seem to be related to the login itself as I get: `gdm-password][73753]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring` without a delayed timestamp. I'd still like to find out what causes the screen to freeze..